# How to get nested values from an object and push to another newly created object/document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, nested-lists

I'm still learning NodeJs and MongoDB. I'm sorry if this might be a simple question for some. I'm working on a project but I'm stuck and not sure what to do.

I created 2 collections: "carts" and "orders".

In the carts document I have this (example):

```
        /* 1 */
        {
            "_id" : "11111",
            "userId" : "88888",
            "productId" : "oranges",
            "quantity" : 10,
        }
        /* 2 */
        {
            "_id" : "22222",
            "userId" : "88888",
            "productId" : "apples",
            "quantity" : 5,
        }
        /* 3 */
        {
            "_id" : "33333",
            "userId" : "77777",
            "productId" : "grapes",
            "quantity" : 5,
        }
```

In the orders collection I have this:

```
          /* 1 */
         {
         "userId": "88888",
         "products": [{
              "productId": xxxxxx ,
              "quantity":  xx
          }],
         "totalAmount": xx
         }
```

Now I used `Cart.find({userId: 88888})` to see all "carts" with userId 8888. It gives me an object with all those carts. But how can I push the productIds and corresponding quantities to that single order document with "userId":"88888"? I need to be able to create a function in mongodb /nodejs to create a new order object. I'm hoping to be able to get something like this:

```
        /* 1 */
        {
          "userId": "88888",
          "products": [
            {
             "productId": "oranges",
             "quantity":  10
            },
            {
              "productId": "apples",
              "quantity":  5
            },
           ],
          "totalAmount": xx
         }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to take the result of `Cart.find({userId: 88888})`  query and insert it alongside `totalAmount` in a single orders document?

Comment: I want to take only the "productId/quantity" and their values and insert it as an array of objects under "products" in a single orders document. :)